# How to properly migrate class/module used by pickle files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Assume there are 2 external modules, `moduleA` and `moduleB`. They contain a same class `moduleA.myClass` and `moduleB.myClass`. The two class are the same (or at least the same in a duck typing sense). The two modules are out of my control.

I have a bunch of pickle files, containing instances of `moduleA.myClass`. I need to use them in an environment that only `moduleB` is available. So I have to transform these `moduleA.myClass` instance pickles to `moduleB.myClass` instance pickles. For this purpose, I can set up a temporary environment that both `moduleA` and `moduleB` are available.

The question is, how I should achieve this, or if there is a better idea other than what I wanted to do.

Comment: What makes you think this is even possible?

Comment: Well at least some very dirty tricks can work, like extending some methods inside pickle module or doing something to sys.modules dict etc. And from some search it seems possible to change the class of an instance. I want to see if there is any way less dirty, and ideally all tricks can be done in a one-off way so that I can get new pickles to work with normally.

Comment: There may be some hacky ways of doing it, but there's are no "proper" ones that I am aware of.